# keras train LSTM model on vgg16 features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Am creating abnormal behaviour detection model, so for this purpose am using vgg16 pretrained module to extract features, so am using `fc2` layer to get the features i get (1,4096) as shape for these features,

```
base_model = VGG16(weights=weights, include_top=include_top)
base_model.compile(optimizer=SGD(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=base_model.get_layer('fc2').output)
print(model.summary())
image_size = (224, 224)
```

this is how i defined vgg16 model,,  and get the features, using predict before last softmax activation layer.

```
img = np.array(cv2.resize(image, image_size))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
feature = model.predict(x)
```

and , when looked for the shape of features,

```
print feature.shape
```

> i get :, (1,4096)

and here am using Bidirectional-LSTM for sequential classification problem, which is conventional way for these kinds of probem, but as per keras documentation, LSTM takes three dimensional training samples , to fit for that like `(224, 224, 3)`, but am getting only 1D features,, so is it possible to train LSTM on dimensions of above extracted feature, or is there any alternate solution to this, like reshaping features to 3D channel, but it's not possible due to feature length, and it needs more feature length to reshape it to `(224, 224, 3)`.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=HIDDEN_UNITS, return_sequences=True),
                        input_shape=(self.expected_frames, self.num_input_tokens)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(self.nb_classes))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage VGG16 features work with LSTM?